# What is the euclidean curvature at the origin for the surface $z = x^4 + y^4 - 2x^2y^2$?

Tags: differential-geometry

This is the graph of $z=x^4 + y^4 - 2x^2*y^2$:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIIg8.png)

From my understanding, the euclidian curvature is the product of the principal curvatures, but I am not sure whether to take the curvatures along the $x$ and $y$ axis or the curvatures along $x = y$ and $x = -y$ as principal curvatures as they seem to yield different values.

Sorry for my bad english, thank you.

Comment: Is the function written correctly?  $x^4+y^4-2x^2y^2=(x^2-y^2)^2$ is everywhere nonnegative but your image does not conform with that.

Comment: sorry, i removed the axes. the equation is indeed correct

Comment: Still not conforming.  Curve in image dips below what appears to be the origin, function you wrote is everywhere nonnegative.  I am confused.

Comment: sorry for the bad graph, hope this is a better view: https://imgur.com/oK5apOf

Comment: This is what I expected to see from the function.  Now I will tell you there should be zero local curvature in all directions.  Can you show what you got?

Comment: In fact, the origin is an umbilic of this surface: The normal curvature $0$ in every direction.

Comment: i am confused, if i take curvatures along the x and y axes, both principal curvatures are both zero, so the euclidian curvature is indeed zero. But, if i take curvatures along y=x and y=-x, both principal curvatures are positive, so the euclidian curvature appears positive.